# Date picker inside of ajax returned html content

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

**Update:** the `.click` that I was using and the `.find` method below in the comments, both add the `.hasDatepicker` class to the input.  It doesn't however show the datepicker.

**Update2:** The datepicker was displaying but was about 1000px too high.  It appears to be how the `datepicker` function grabs it's coordinates.  It doesn't work well when it is buried in the `success or complete` portion of the `ajax` call.  I had to grab the `x,y` of the input at the top of `ajaxComplete` in a separate script.  That did get the correct coordinates.  See my answer below.

---

jQuery Datepicker **works if I use an input that is there on page load**.

But if I bring it in via Ajax, it doesn't work.

Here is my current html setup:

```
<body>
    <select id="product_selector">Options</select>
    <div id="targetdiv"></div>
</body>
```

The ajax brings in a bunch of inputs (no form element around them) and the one in particular (appended to #targetdiv) that is supposed to be the **DatePicker** is this one:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker"  name="cmdz_end_date" id="cmdz_end_date" placeholder="End Date">
```

So far **I am able to console.log when I click inside of the ajax delivered input** but I am not able to get the date picker to show up. Here is the JS I have so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#product_selector').on('change', function() {
    var product = this.value;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" ,
        data: {"action": "manual_transaction_form_select", "product": product},
        complete: function(){
                //$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
        },
        success: function(data){ 
            add_html_to_page(data);
                    $('#targetdiv').html(data).find('.datepicker').datepicker();
           // $('#targetdiv').on("click", ".datepicker", function(event) {
              //  console.log('click');
         //     $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
            //});
         }
    });
});

 function add_html_to_page(data){
    $('#targetdiv').empty().append(data)
 }
});
```

I have tried using the .datepicker in 'complete' and 'success' to no avail.  It's probably because I am not targeting it correctly but I am not sure how to get there.  In the .on("click" it registers to console but it does not make the field utilize .datepicker

WP Version: 3.8

Any insight on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `$('#targetdiv').html(data).find('.datepicker').datepicker()` in the success callback? And you know you're targeting `.datepickers` with an **s** in the click function?

Comment: The `.click` your method both add the `.hasDatepicker` class to the input element, but it doesn't display the datepicker.  The `.datepickers` was left because I changed a bunch of the names when I posted.

Comment: Have you ever check response data on your ajax request?  And is there any error on firbug console?

Comment: It brings back the HTML that is displayed on the page.  I guess I'm not sure what you are asking for there since it is displaying correctly and when I inspect it it looks good.   I do have an error in Chrome Console: `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead` but I believe that was there before I started to setup the ajax etc...

Comment: Open your console and check for errors.

Comment: Been doing that... none to report.  Only a deprecated warning to report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me with the date picker displaying in the correct place.  Initially the jquery datepicker probably was displaying but it couldn't be seen because it was  at the top of the page by the `<select>`.  If I placed the code in the ajax success or complete of the main script then `$('#cmdz_end_date).offset()` would return an incorrect value that would be essentially the same as the `<select>` `offset()`

If anyone could enlighten me on why this was the case I would be very appreciative.

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
    var xy = jQuery('#cmdz_end_date').offset();
    jQuery('#cmdz_end_date').datepicker({
        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                inst.dpDiv.css({
                    top: xy.top,
                    left: xy.left
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead:

```
success: function(data){ 
    add_html_to_page(data, function(){
        $('#targetdiv datepicker').datepicker();
    });
}
```

this way the `.datepicker()` will be a callback of your `add_html_to_page()` and only run after it's finished

EDIT:

If the previous one didn't work I guess it's because the callback wasn't placed in the right place, can you try this code please:

```
    success: function(data){ 
        add_html_to_page(data);
    }
```

and

```
function add_html_to_page(data){
    $('#targetdiv').html(data, function(){
        $('#targetdiv datepicker').datepicker();
    });
}
```

Comment: This does display the HTML but does not add the `.hasDatepicker` class so I don't think that it is working.  The other option using .find does add the class but it's not showing the datepicker

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  It doesn't appear that the `HTML` is loaded into the `DOM` at that point so it isn't finding it. That's the only reason that I can see why your edit isn't working for me.  It does work to put `datepicker()` on the next line down but then I ran into a scope issue: the coordinates for the datepicker box were off by about a 1000 px.  It looks like you have to grab the coords at the top level of `ajaxComplete` not in the ajax call/success/complete.   That is why I put together a seperate script to look for that.  I am sure there is a better way to do it but that is working.

Comment: it could be a css issue, you need to make sure the element which I guess it's empty and not being displayed should have the same coordinates as if it had visible content

Comment: Ultimately it is a CSS issue... but `datepicker()` gets the absolute positioning `x,y` for the css from where it is instantiated.  Problem is, when it is nested in that Ajax call it gets coordinates that are inline with the top of the DIV where the HTML is added.  So I had to grab the `x,y` at the very top of the script on `ajaxComplete`.